# Angular Translate - Unknown provider: $translateProviderProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I was implementing angular translate in my project and everything works fine, but when I've moved my `$translateProvider`from my `config` block to my `controller.js`, I'm getting this error:

> Unknown provider: $translateProviderProvider <- $translateProvider <-
>   myController

But every module seems to be correctly referenced, am I missing something here? or maybe this translations can't work inside of a controller?

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myapp.controller', ['pascalprecht.translate'])

    .controller('myController', 
        ['$translateProvider', 
        function ($translateProvider) {

            function init() {
                $translateProvider.useUrlLoader('myweb.com/api/lang', {
                    queryParameter : 'en_US'
                });
                $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
            }

            init(); 
    }]);
```

**UPDATE**

Now I know that $translateProvider are not available to use it in controller class.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I don't want to load all the traductions files from the rest, because there are many components that the user never see, so if I go to the page that contains ng-controller="myController", the init() function should call to the rest and get the traductions only for the current component. I've found this on the documentation:

```
angular.module('contact')
.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $translatePartialLoader) {
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('contact');
});
```

But how can I:

1. Specify the URL for my REST?
2. Specify the parameter 'contact' in the URL to my REST know that it should retrieve me the traductions only for the contact component.

Answer (score 4):

When injecting a provider in a controller, you don't need the Provider suffix.

just inject it as

```
.controller('myController', ['$translate', function ($translate) { ... }])
```

Comment: Hi @NeilS but after that change i'm getting the error: $translate.useUrlLoader is not a function

Comment: The translate service doesn't have that method available, it looks like those methods are only available to use within the config of your angular app.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you should check the translate docs on how (and why) to use the translate service - https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service

Comment: I think you should check out the section called Using staticFilesLoader on https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading